# is it possible to write a program in python that will ask the user to enter the output of an array?

Tags: java, python

I want to learn how to write a simple program in python, I know little about java and I wonder if it is possible to write similar program in python.

it is possible to write similar program like this in python

//This is my java code

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Number of Rows: ");
    int row=scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the Number of Columns");
    int column=scanner.nextInt();
    int[][] array=new int [row][column];
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<array[0].length;j++){
            array[i][j]=5;
            System.out.print(array[i][j]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}
//Sample output

Enter the Number of Rows:

3

Enter the Number of Columns:

2

5   5
5   5
5   5

Comment: `print("\n".join(int(input("Enter the Number of Rows: ")) * ["\t".join("5" for _ in range(int(input("Enter the Number of Columns: "))))] ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example Code**

```
nrows = int(input("Enter the Number of Rows: "))
ncolumns = int(input("Enter the Number of Columns: "))
arr = [[5]*ncolumns for _ in range(nrows)]  # create nrows x ncolumns of 5
for row in range(nrows):
    print(*arr[row], sep = '\t')  # *arr[row] unpacks a row at a time for printing
```

**Sample Run**

```
Enter the Number of Rows: 3
Enter the Number of Columns: 2
5   5
5   5
5   5
```